# In .NET is there a class of constants for setting HttpResponse.StatusDescription?

Tags: c#, .net, httpresponse, status

I am using c# and modifying the `HttpResponse` returned from the server. I have found an enumeration which has all the relevant status *codes* in `HttpStatusCode` but i am having trouble finding an accompanying class which holds string constants to set the `HttpResponse.StatusDescription` property.

Is it simply the case that it doesn't exist? Or that the description is effectively free-text, as long as you set something relatively descriptive you'll be ok?

Thanks in advance for the help,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are largely free to insert whatever text you want into the StatusDescription, as long as the string does not exceed the maximum lenght allowed by HTTP (iirc this is 512 characters).

As an example if you were to set a 500 error (internal server error) you could put a further description in to allow invokers to get additional information relating to the error that occurred.

The StatusDescription property defaults to "OK"

A little more information can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statusdescription.aspx

It is also worth mentioning that in most implementations the value of status description is not used.  Most service invokers use the actual status code to determine success, failure or other conditions (i.e. redirected, not found etc)

Comment: `You are largely free to insert whatever text you want...` Is that true?  Can an HTTP application return a status of "200 Happy Birthday", and still be in compliance with RFC2616 ?

Comment: The RFC doesn't give any specific guidance, have a look at sections 6.1.1 and 10

Comment: thanks for the answer, very informative.  I'm gonna petitions W3C for "Happy Birthday" to be default value :-)

Answer (score 4):

You could just use `HttpStatusCode.*MEMBER*.ToString()` to get the string value of the Enumeration.

Example: `HttpStatusCode.OK.ToString()`

Comment: good point. though it might not be very user friendly to have a camel case string as description, but i suppose HTTP headers were never designed with user-friendliness in mind anyway!!

Comment: @WickyNilliams Then simply add `.ToLower()` or `.ToUpper()`